# Highstock: Adding a scatter series doesn't seem to work

Tags: highcharts

I can't seem to add a scatter series to a highstock chart. See this fiddle, using one of your modified examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/q52AQ/

```
$(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        chart: {
        },

        navigator: {
            series: {
                color: 'green'  
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: usdeur,
            type: 'scatter'
        }]
    });
});
```

It should be a simple one to figure out, but I can't see what's wrong.

EDIT:
I've found that it works with the following source script:
"http://github.highcharts.com/v3.0Beta/highstock.js"

What is the difference between this and the 1.3 Highstock release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it looks like a bug so I've reported to our developers here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1853

Comment: Ah, is gitHub the best place to log issues in that case? I have another one that's causing an issue as well.

Comment: You can add information about additinal circumstances to github thread.